# Trouble with json_decode

Tags: php, json

For some reason I cannot seem to get json_decode to pull out the id I need. Perhaps I have a syntax error in this code? The code otherwise works. If I manually provide the id in between the two API calls it completes successfully. Also, I have not really been able to easily debug this because I am calling this PHP function using ajax and an html button and I dont really know Ajax at all, so I dont know how to print debug echo messages in the PHP code as I usually would to see where I am having trouble. So basically I am troubleshooting this blind.

Basically the code does an initial API call to find the VM with the tag "VMTAG". The API call returns JSON info for that VM. I extract the ID with json_decode, then I do a second API call shutting down the VM using that ID.

```
function shutdown() {
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets?tag_name=VMTAG');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Bearer TOKENHIDDEN',
        'Content-Type: application/json')
    );
    $json = curl_exec($ch);
    $object = json_decode($json);
    $id = $object['id'];
    $data = array("type" => "shutdown");
    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets/' . $id . '/actions');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Bearer TOKENHIDDEN',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Look into CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER

Comment: Can you expand? To fix which issue?

Comment: Can you show us the JSON returned?

Comment: If you watch the request/response in the browser's developer tools you can echo out everything you need for troubleshooting, just as you would normally, without AJAX.

Comment: As for as the return transfer it should be included as one of your `$curl_setopt` declarations, prior to executing the cURL.

Comment: on the first call, you are json_decoding to a stdClass... and using it as an array, Pick one but not both.

Comment: @Atomiklan: have you looked at the PHP documentation for curl_setopt, regarding CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER? If you read the one paragraph, I think you'll come up with the answer to your problem. One of the problems seems to be that you pass a curl handle to json_decode.

Comment: Hello again Jay! Yes I have been trying to use the browser tools, but doesnt give me as warm a feeling as does just inserting echo statements to test. Most of this code is not written directly by me. I have never used PHP this way to interface with Digital Ocean. I'm a physicist, not a programmer haha. So most of this is new to me. Apparently I dont fully understand what takes place between the calls. Can you give me some example code and explanation please?

Comment: I added curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); to the first call and took @YvesLeBorg suggestion below. Seems like both calls are running, but its still not getting the id. {"id":"not_found","message":"The resource you were accessing could not be found."} ie it seems $id is still not getting set.

Comment: Actually it is probably getting set to "not_found" ... you should review the api documentation for the service you are trying to consume on the first call. Possibly you are not using it as per the api's design specifications.

Comment: The first call comes back fine. It pulls the VM with the correct tag and I get a JSON output of all the VM details. The first item of the JSON string is the VM ID.

Comment: Any more suggestions?

Comment: Can anyone else help with this? The id is still not being pulled out.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
$object = json_decode($json); // this gives a stdClass
$id = $object['id'];          // you are using $object as an assoc. array
```

instead,

```
$object = json_decode($json,true); // now you have an assoc array and 
$id = $object['id'];               // $id should now be defined
```

see the docs for json_decode :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Added your suggestion. See comment above.